# Facing issue in implementation of EventSystem

Tags: event-system

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1, We are facing error `Unable to create an Eventsystem Object`.  As debugging is not working we have implemented custom logging.  We found that `Subscribe` function is getting called, but `OnComponentSavePre` function is not getting called. Below is the code we have written

```
using System;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events;
using System.IO;

namespace TridionMetadataUpdateEvent
{
    [TcmExtension("Tridion2011EventSystem")]  
    public class EventSystem : TcmExtension
    {
        public EventSystem()
        {
            StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"D:\data.txt");
            writer.WriteLine("Event Execution Started.");
            writer.Close();
            Subscribe();
        }

        public void Subscribe()
        {
            StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"D:\data.txt");
            writer.WriteLine("Inside Subscribe.");
            writer.Close();
            try
            {
                EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, SaveEventArgs>(OnComponentSavePre, EventPhases.Initiated);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                StreamWriter writer2 = File.AppendText(@"D:\data.txt");
                writer2.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                writer2.Close();
            }
        }

        private static void OnComponentSavePre(Component comp, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"D:\data.txt");
            writer.WriteLine("Inside OnComponentSavePre.");
            writer.Close();
            //sample code we will be writting here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To debug, in the Visual Studio debug window, select the 'show processes from all users' and chose the one for dllhost that the MTSUser is running.  You can find the process also in the processes list from The Task Manager and copy the PID number.  If running in debug mode on the server it should step into the debugger.

Comment: Unable to create an event system object is a COM error. You are probably enabling (or still have enabled) the Event in the MMC snap-in instead of using the new mechanism to register the event in code only.

Comment: Thanks Nuno, Yes we had oncomponentsavepre event enabled in MMC snap in, after disabling it our code started working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check for the following:
1) IN Tridion Content Manager config file on CMS server, ensure that all correct EventSystem DLLs has been subscribed, there is no unwanted DLLs registered and the path of the desired even system dlls is correct

2) As Nuno suggested, check in SDL Tridion Configuration Manager, that older COM+ event system are not enabled

Answer (score 13):

As Nuno commented, that error is about the old legacy VB event system. You can disable that if you are not using it and just have your new .NET assembly running instead (which doesn't require any further configuration).

I have no problems running and debugging that code (attaching to TcmServiceHost.exe) so the problem is likely that your extension hasn't been loaded.

Check for errors in the Event Viewer, double-check the path/assembly information in Tridion.ContentManager.config, and restart the Tridion Content Manager Service Host to make sure your new extension is being loaded.